# CSS3 animation is not working in windows safari

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

CSS3 animation is not working properly in safari and its working in all other browsers.

**OS:** Windows

HTML

```
<img src='../images/image1.png' class='test' />
```

CSS

```
   .test {
      animation: test 2s ease;
      -webkit-animation: test 2s ease; 
   }

   @keyframes test {
        0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% {
            content: url('../images/image2.png');
        }

        10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
            content: url('../images/image1.png');
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes test {
        0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% {
            content: url('../images/image2.png');            
        }

        10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
            content: url('../images/image1.png');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Safari for Windows was like version 5, I wouldn't expect anything modern to work. Apple stopped to support it in 2012.

Comment: @pawel: So you said, it will work in mac safari at latest version right?